# Proper way to extract value from DataFrame with composite index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, call it current_data.  This dataframe is generated via running statistical functions over another dataframe, current_data_raw.  It has a compound index on columns "Method" and "Request.Name"

`current_data = current_data_raw.groupby(['Name', 'Request.Method']).size().reset_index().set_index(['Name', 'Request.Method'])`

I then run a bunch of statistical functions over `current_data_raw` adding new columns to `current_data`

I then need to query that dataframe for specific values of columns.  I would love to do something like:

`val = df['Request.Name' == some_name, 'Method' = some_method]['Average']`

However this isn't working, nor are the varients I have attempted above.  `.xs` is returning a series.  I could grab the only row in the series but that doesn't seem proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want select in `MultiIndex` is possible use tuple in order of levels, but here is not specified index name like `'Request.Name'`:

```
val = df.loc[(some_name, some_method), 'Average']
```

Another way is use [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), but if levels names contains spaces or `.` is necessary use backticks:

```
val = df.query("`Request.Name`=='some_name' & `Request.Method`=='some_method'")['Average']
```

If one word levels names:

```
val = df.query("Name=='some_name' & Method=='some_method'")['Average']
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  Is there a supply names to `.loc` so that I do not need to preserve the ordering of the levels?

Comment: @user731842 - Unfortunately not, then only way is use `df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('Request.Name') == 'some_name') & (df.index.get_level_values('Request.Method') == 'some_method'), 'Average']`